# How to make sure device supports "step counter sensor" or "step detector sensor" BEFORE installation from Google Play?

Tags: java, android, manifest, sensors

Is there any way to filter devices in the manifest file, or in the Play Console, or anywhere else, that don't support either the "pedometer sensor" or the "step detector sensor", but have the app install on devices that do support one of the sensors?

Of course, in Google Play Console I could check all available devices' hardware support lists and disable each device which is not supporting any of those sensors, but that seems to be very faulty and time consuming, so I'm looking for a more convenient way.

I created my first app from scratch, Simple Stepper, it is a step tracking app. So far it works quite well. In the code, I differentiate whether the device the app is installed on supports either the "step counter sensor" or the "step detector sensor". The sensor found is then used to detect steps. If both are present, the "step counter sensor" is used.

However, I found that some people who downloaded my app were unable to use it because neither of the above sensors were found. To spare other users this bad experience, I implemented a runtime-check that tells the user on first launch that they cannot use the app if both sensors are not present. This has worked well so far.

But I was unhappy with this solution as it gives users, who downloaded the app, a bad experience where the app doesn't run. To make sure that no other user gets frustrated, I was wondering if there is a way to make sure that one of these sensors is available on the user's device **BEFORE** installation, and if not, to not let the user download the app in the first place, or even better, hide it from them completely.

So I found, that one could use following flags in manifest file:

```
<uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter" 
android:required="true" />
```

And

```
<uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector" 
android:required="true" />
```

But I couldn't find a way to check if one **OR** the other sensor is available. It seems that I can only check if both are available (set both to true) or neither (set both to false).

Or maybe someone know, if "step detector sensor" is always available when "step counter sensor" is available, but not vice versa. In that case, I would only use the flag for the "step counter sensor" to filter the app in Google Play. And on runtime just use the "step counter sensor" if it is available. But I could not find information of that.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: "It seems that I can only check if both are available (set both to true) or neither (set both to false)" -- that is not what `android:required="false"` means. `android:required="false"` means "the feature is not required" not "the feature is not available". That said, this statement is correct: "But I couldn't find a way to check if one OR the other sensor is available". The fact that the two sensors have separate features suggests that it is possible for a device to have one or the other but not both. I do not know how common that is, though.

Comment: Greetings! Yes, you seem right, about the meaning of android:required="false". But from what I read, the defualt state, so if you don't enter anything in manifest file, would be also android:required="false". And that would imply, that nothing would change, if I added those two lines. Or am I assuming/implying it wrongly?

Comment: "But from what I read, the defualt state, so if you don't enter anything in manifest file, would be also android:required="false"" -- correct.

Answer (score 0):

We can check for sensor availability with `SensorManager`. We can use `getSensorList` method to check and get a list for all available sensors and iterate through the list to check the availability of the desired sensor.

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

// Check for pedometer sensor
Sensor pedometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
boolean hasPedometer = pedometerSensor != null;

// Check for step detector sensor
Sensor stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
boolean hasStepDetector = stepDetectorSensor != null;
```

and then handle it according to your app business logic.

```
if (hasPedometer || hasStepDetector) {
    // Allow the app to function
} else {
    // Display a message to the user indicating the sensor requirements
}
```

GitHub link to my repo to check Sensor Availability at Runtime.
[Check Sensor Availabilty](https://github.com/sarmadalij/CheckingSensorAvailability/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sarmadali/checkingsensor)

Comment: Greetings! Thanks for reply, but it is not what I meant. I'm looking for a way to check sensors BEFORE installation NOT at runtime. Cheers

Comment: I see, Unfortunately, it is not possible to verify the availability of a specific feature before installation. The Google Play Store does not provide a mechanism to check for device features or sensor availability during the installation process. However, using some different approach you can manage that, As per online data available I have seen that Step Detector sensor was introduced in Android 4.4 KitKat (API level 19). In your app's manifest file, you can use the <uses-sdk> element to specify the minimum API level. It will ensure  only devices with Android 4.4 will be eligible to install.

Comment: But, this is only compatible when you have small app that uses just that one feature. Let's assume a scenario where we are using feature Abc that is only available to Api level above 25+ and there is another feature xyz that is available to Api level 20+, if you want to check for feature Abc in android app and want to restrict the device to install the app Below 25+ because user will not be eligible to use feature Abc, then there is xyz feature that is available but due to device not supportting feature Abc, then user will also not be able to use feature xyz. And can't install the app.

Comment: So, in my pov, it is best practice to check for the availability of any feature at runtime, and manage it within your app business logic. So if user can use the features he is eligible for. And if the user is not eligible then manage that in your app and inform the unavailability of that feature in his android version, and inform the user that he can't use specific functions of the app due to unavailability of that feature.

Comment: Regarding the scenario, we can also set the minimum Api level to 20+ so user can use both features, but if we wanted to check for both features availability based on Api levels, then restrict the app to that device that do not meets the requirements for both features, then this conflict will occur.

Comment: Thanks for explenation. I also thought of api restrictions, like you mentioned, but I hoped for a more convenient way. And I wonder, why it is so hard, to distinguish if the device offers the one or the other sensor, or none. I guess it must be a quite common issue. Very disappointing Google!!! ;]